# rewritten: Vue 3 component as re-usable lib, renders during development but not after build

Tags: vue.js, flask, vuejs3, vue-component, vue-composition-api

I am attempting to create a re-usable vue component that can be injected/used in a flask application. The main component dataTable.vue imports components tableBare.vue and paginationBare.vue, including the composable dataTable.js.

My files:

```
src/components/dataTable.vue (main SFC)
src/components/dataTable.js
src/components/tableBare.vue
src/components/paginationBare.vue
```

dataTable.vue imports the other 3 files

dataTable.vue is built with

`vue-cli-service build --inline-vue --target lib --name data-table src/components/dataTable.vue`

The generated output after build is rendered within a flask/jinja template (about.html, below). During the development, table-bare and pagination-bare render correctly, but after building and in the flask app, table-bare and pagination-bare (both sub-components) do not render on page. Inspecting the Elements tab, I found out the following:

*During development, pagination-bare renders as:*

```
<ul data-v-6220917c="" class="pagination">
  <li data-v-6220917c="" class="page-item-clickable disabled">
    <a data-v-6220917c="" class="page-link">«</a>
  </li>
  <li data-v-6220917c="" class="page-item-clickable active">
    <a data-v-6220917c="" class="page-link">1</a>
  </li>
  <li data-v-6220917c="" class="page-item-clickable">
    <a data-v-6220917c="" class="page-link">2</a>
  </li>
  <li data-v-6220917c="" class="page-item-clickable">
    <a data-v-6220917c="" class="page-link">3</a>
  </li>
  <li data-v-6220917c="" class="page-item-clickable">
    <a data-v-6220917c="" class="page-link">4</a>
  </li>
  <li data-v-6220917c="" class="page-item-clickable">
    <a data-v-6220917c="" class="page-link">5</a>
  </li>
  <li data-v-6220917c="" class="page-item-clickable disabled">
    <a data-v-6220917c="" class="page-link">...</a>
  </li>
  <li data-v-6220917c="" class="page-item-clickable">
    <a data-v-6220917c="" class="page-link">25</a>
  </li>
  <li data-v-6220917c="" class="page-item-clickable">
    <a data-v-6220917c="" class="page-link">»</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

*After build, with flask/jinja:*

```
<pagination-bare current-page="1" total-rows="123" per-page="10"></pagination-bare>
```

`Table-bare` has the same problem.

What is wrong with my code?

**dataTable.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>

    <CAlert color="info" dismissible>
      <strong>Here</strong> datatables will rise.
    </CAlert>

    <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
      <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> You should check in on some of those fields below.
      <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
    </div>

    <div id="edit_form" v-if="editing" class="edit-section col-md-6 ">
        <h2><div v-if="adding">Add user</div><div v-else>Edit user "form.username"</div></h2>
        <form @submit.prevent="onSubmitForm">
          <slot name="editForm"></slot>

          <CButton
              color="primary"
              class="me-1"
              type="submit"
          >Submit</CButton>

          <CButton
              @click.prevent="editing = adding = false"
              color="secondary"
              type="cancel"
          >Cancel</CButton>
        </form>
    </div>


    <div v-if="!editing" class="table-section">
        <h2>[[ capitalize(title) ]]</h2>
            <div v-if="totalRows>0" class="form-row">

                <div class="col-sm-7 my-2">
                    <CButton
                            @click="editing = adding = true"
                            color="primary">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                            <span class="d-none d-md-inline"> Add [[capitalize(title_s)]]</span>
                    </CButton>
                    <small v-if="Object.keys(selected).length===0" class="text-muted ms-2">
                      Click a row to edit or delete.
                    </small>
                    <span v-else>
                        <CButton
                                @click="editing = true"
                                class="ms-1" color="secondary">
                                <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                                <span class="d-none d-md-inline"> Edit</span>
                        </CButton>
                        <CButton
                                @click="showMsgBoxConfirm"
                                class="ms-1"
                                color="secondary"><i class="fa fa-trash">
                                </i><span class="d-none d-md-inline"> Delete</span>
                        </CButton>
                    </span>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-5 my-2">
                    <!-- filter box -->
                </div>
            </div>

        <table-bare :items="items"
                   :fields="fields"
                   :sort-by="sortBy"
                   :sort-desc="sortDesc"
                   @changeSortBy="changeSortBy"
                   @rowClick="rowClick"
        ></table-bare>



        <div v-if="totalRows>0" class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2 mb-1">
                <select v-model="perPage" class="form-select" id="perPageOptions">
                  <option v-for="(opt, idx) in perPageOptions" v-bind:key="idx" :value="opt.value" >
                    [[opt.label]]
                  </option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 mb-1">
              <pagination-bare
                :current-page="currentPage"
                :total-rows="totalRows"
                :per-page="perPage"
                @pageChanged="pageChanged"
              ></pagination-bare>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- <div v-else>No data to display.</div> -->

  </div>
</template>



<script>
import DataTable from '@/components/dataTable.js';
import { useCapitalize } from '@/composables/stringUtils';
import { ref } from 'vue';
import tableBare from '@/components/tableBare.vue';
import PaginationBare from '@/components/paginationBare.vue';
import { CAlert,  CButton, 
        } from '@coreui/bootstrap-vue';


export default {
    components: {
    'table-bare': tableBare, PaginationBare,
    CAlert,   CButton, 
},
    props: ['apiEndpoint'],
    setup(props) {

        const { flashMessage, flashMessageVariant, 
          adding, editing, title, selected, items, fields,
          currentPage, perPage, perPageOptions, totalRows,
          onRowSelected, onFiltered,
          onSortChanged, onSubmitForm, onPageChange,
          unselectRows,
          sortBy, sortDesc, filter } = DataTable();
        console.log(props.apiEndpoint)

        // mutate title
        var title_s
        let title_temp
        title_temp = title.value.split('|')
        title_s = title_temp[0]
        title.value = title_temp.length > 1 ? title_temp[1] : title_temp[0]

        editing.value = false
        
        const mybtableRef = ref(null)

        function showMsgBoxConfirm() {
          // dummy
        }

        function pageChanged(page) {
          currentPage.value = page
          // fetchData('page')
        }

        function rowClick(rowData, idx) {
          unselectRows(idx)
          rowData.selected = !rowData.selected
          selected.value = rowData.selected ? [rowData] : []
        }

        function changeSortBy(sortByVal, sortDescVal) {
          sortBy.value = sortByVal
          sortDesc.value = sortDescVal
        }

        return { 
            flashMessage,
            flashMessageVariant,
            adding,
            editing,
            title, title_s,
            showMsgBoxConfirm,
            selected,
            capitalize:useCapitalize,
            items, fields,
            currentPage, perPage, perPageOptions, totalRows,
            sortBy, sortDesc, filter,
            onRowSelected, onFiltered, onSortChanged,
            onSubmitForm, onPageChange,
            mybtableRef, changeSortBy, rowClick,
            pageChanged,
            }
    }
}

</script>

<style scoped>
  @import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
</style>
```

**paginationBare.vue**

```
<template>
    <nav aria-label="Table navigation">
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li class="page-item-clickable" :class="{disabled:currentPage==1}">
            <a class="page-link" @click="onPagerClick('prev')">&laquo;</a></li>
        <li v-for="(item, idx) in pageLinks" v-bind:key="idx" 
            class="page-item-clickable" :class="{disabled:item=='...', active:item==currentPage}"
        >
            <a class="page-link" @click="onPagerClick(item)">[[item]]</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item-clickable" :class="{disabled:currentPage==lastPage}">
            <a class="page-link" @click="onPagerClick('next')">&raquo;</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue';
export default {
    name: 'pagination-bare',
    props: ['currentPage', 'totalRows', 'perPage'],
    setup(props, ctx) {
        const lastPage = Math.ceil( props.totalRows / parseInt(props.perPage) )

        var pageLinks = ref([])
        pageLinks.value = getPageLinks(props.currentPage)

        function getPageLinks(curPage) {
            let pageLinks = []
            if (lastPage < 8) {
                pageLinks = Array(lastPage).fill(0).map((x, i) => i + 1)
            } else if (curPage < 5) {
                pageLinks = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, '...', lastPage]
            } else if ((curPage > (lastPage - 4))) {
                pageLinks = [1, '...', lastPage-4, lastPage-3, lastPage-2, lastPage-1, lastPage]
            } else {
                pageLinks = [1, '...', curPage-1, curPage, curPage+1, '...', lastPage]
            }
            return pageLinks
     
        }

        function onPagerClick(data) {
            let newPage
            if (data=='next') {
                newPage = props.currentPage +1
            } else if (data=='prev') {
                newPage = props.currentPage -1
            } else {
                newPage = data
            }
            ctx.emit('pageChanged', newPage)
            pageLinks.value = getPageLinks(newPage)
        }

        return {
            lastPage, pageLinks,
            onPagerClick,
        }
    }

}
</script>

<style scoped>
.page-item-clickable {
    @extend .page-item;
    cursor: pointer;
}

li.disabled {
  cursor:auto;
}
li.disabled a {
  pointer-events: none;
}
</style>
```

**tableBare.vue**

```
<template>
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th v-for="(fld, index) in fields" v-bind:key="index"
                    @click="onHeaderClick(fld)"
                >
                    <span v-if="(typeof fld==='string')" >
                        [[fld]]
                    </span>
                    <span v-else>[[fld.key]]
                        <i v-if="(['true', true].includes(fld.sortable))" 
                            class="fas"
                            :class="{'fa-sort sort-off': sortBy!=fld.key,
                              'fa-sort-down': sortBy==fld.key && !sortDesc,
                              'fa-sort-up': sortBy==fld.key && sortDesc,
                              }"
                            >
                        </i>
                    </span>
                    <span 
                        v-if="typeof fld==='string' ? sortBy==fld : sortBy==fld.key " 
                        class="badge text-bg-light sort-badge"
                        @click.stop="onClickSortBadge">x</span>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr v-for="(v1, k1) in items" v-bind:key="k1"
                :class="{'table-active' : v1.selected}"
                @click="onRowClick(v1, k1)">
                <td v-for="(v2, k2) in v1" v-bind:key="k2">
                    <template v-if="fields_simple.includes(k2)">[[v2]]</template></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    name: 'table-bare',
    props: ['items', 'fields', 'sortBy', 'sortDesc'],
    setup(props, ctx) {

        const fields_simple = props.fields.map(function(n) {
            if (typeof n==='string') {
                return n
            } else {
                return n.key
            }
        })

        function onClickSortBadge() {
            ctx.emit('changeSortBy', '', '')
        }

        function onHeaderClick(fld) {
            if (typeof fld==='string') {
                ctx.emit('changeSortBy', '', '')
            } else {
                if (fld.key == props.sortBy) {
                    ctx.emit('changeSortBy', fld.key, !props.sortDesc)    
                } else {
                    ctx.emit('changeSortBy', fld.key, false)
                }
            }
        }

        function onRowClick(rowData, idx) {
            ctx.emit('rowClick', rowData, idx)
        }

    return {
        onHeaderClick, onRowClick, fields_simple,
        onClickSortBadge,
    }
    },
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.sort-off {
    color: lightgray
}

.sort-badge {
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
}

/* .badge-sm {
    min-width: 1.8em;
    padding: .25em !important;
    margin-left: .1em;
    margin-right: .1em;
    color: white !important;
    cursor: pointer;
} */
</style>
```

**about.html, flask/jinja template**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block styles %}
    {{ super() }}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='data-table/data-table.css') }}">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"> -->
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h1>About Page</h1>
<p>This is the About page.</p>
<button class="btn btn-info">Check</button>

<div id="app1">
    <data-table :apiEndpoint="'/api_v1/'"></data-table>
</div>

{% endblock %}



{% block scripts %}
    {{ super() }}
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='data-table/data-table.umd.js') }}"></script>
    <script>
        const app1 = Vue.createApp({})
        app1.component('data-table', window['data-table']);
        // app1.component('pagination-bare', window['pagination-bare']);
        app1.mount('#app1')
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You cannot expect window['pagination-bare'] to exist. You need to export all comps from entry point

Comment: My bad, that's just a test code that did nothing. I'm deleting it. Doesn't dataTable.vue component act as entry point for the other 2 sub-components, as they are already imported in there? And thereby, no need to declare them on the flask template?

Comment: This isn't strictly documented, but no. If you didn't explicitly export something from .vue, there's only default export, which is the comp itself - and probably even if you did, because named exports aren't documented in SFC too. There should be index.js entry point, that's how the libs are commonly organized

Comment: As tested, even the simplest child component `<button>Test</button>` won't render. It appears I'm stuck with a single humongous component.